# Is there a way execute an Objective-C application from java?

Tags: java, objective-c

I have an Objective-C console application that already exists.
I'm not the one who developed it, so i don't have easy access to the code.  So changing the code might not be an option, but what i do know is that for compiling, it requires Cocoa and SystemConfiguration.  (i was told in an email)
Once run, it has a prompt waiting for a command and there's a text output result after that command.
Is there a way that i can take this application and run it within java and capture the output?

I've never done OSX development before but i am aware that C code can work well with Java and Obj-c is a superset of C but with the framework requirements, it seems clear that objects are used somewhere in the code.

I have seen something like rococoa but hasn't been updated in some time (2009) does it still work with mountain lion?

Comment: You can run the Objective-C program as a "console" app and capture the "console" output, using Java.  I've done it (a LONG time ago), I believe using Runtime.exec.  The tricky part is catching the console output -- it requires an async thread or something of that nature.

Comment: Looking at Runtime.exec I'm reminded that it returns a Process object.  The console output of the invoked app is available via the "getInputStream" method of Process.  It has to be character mode data, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you have a Objective-C application, you really mean you have a binary/executable compiled for Mac OS?

If so, you can [Class ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create operating system processes.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```

Note: this solution will only work on Mac OS X. Also you might have some security issues because Java loves to run in a sandbox.

Comment: Thank you,  I'll have a look at this option tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a subprocess and also to interchange informations between it and your main program, I think the following code will help you.

It creates a subprocess by calling a binary/executable file, and then writes something (eg. a command) to its input stream and reads some text:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Call_program
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Process the_process = null;
        BufferedReader in_stream = null;
        BufferedWriter out_stream = null;

        try {
            the_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("...");   //replace "..." by the path of the program that you want to call
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("error on exec() method");
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }

        // write to the called program's standard input stream
        try
        {
            out_stream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(the_process.getOutputStream()));
            out_stream.write("...");     //replace "..." by the command that the program is waiting for
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("error on out_stream.write()");
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }

        //read from the called program's standard output stream
        try {
            in_stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(the_process.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(in_stream.readLine());   //you can repeat this line until you find an EOF or an exit code.
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("error when trying to read a line from in_stream");
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}
```

ref.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2frzaha%2fiostrmex.htm

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll do some work around this tomorrow.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this list is comprehensive then there is not a pure Objective-C solution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages

Your next options are solutions to call C from Java - which is easy to Google in its own right so I won't include information here - or more decoupled solutions (which are very likely what you want) e.g. use a message bus, such as ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ.

I strongly recommend avoiding bridging two languages unless you have a particularly unusual architecture or hardware requirement.  Bridging two languages is O(n^2) APIs to learn in the number of languages, implementing message queues is O(n).